# how to combined multiple Handshake messages to a record in java?

Tags: ssl

used java code to request a https site, do tcpdump and find "Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message" will be set to two records:
1. Client Key Exchange
2. Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
how to combined these three Handshake messages to a record in java?

Comment: What do you mean by "a record", especially in which context regarding Java?

Comment: Bruno, he means records as in the TLS protocol, which is the basic protocol data unit (PDU) that is transmitted on the wire.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you care how those are put on the wire? Are you trying to save just a few bytes or have a legitimate real reason for that?

I don't know the specifics of Java's implementation and whether you can influence it through config/params, but from the TLS protocol perspective, it doesn't make any difference how you send handshake messages on the wire. In the case of separate records, you just send some extra bytes, that's all.

Furthermore, for those three in particular, they cannot be combined in a single record and there is a reason for that. The ClientKeyExchange is a plaintext message, so it goes into a record. The ChangeCipherSpec is not a handshake message, rather a record type, therefore it cannot go into the same record as the CKE. Since CCS is a record type on its own, you need to follow it with another handshake message wrapped into a record, therefore you see 3 separate records. Also, the Finished message is encrypted, so you need to add a MAC at the record layer, and cannot be combined with plaintext handshake messages into the same record.

I hope this clears it up a bit.

Comment: Thanks Nasko! But I use wget to request this https site, these three Handshake messages is in a record.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Can you share a network capture? I just tried it and they all show in different records.